# Is temporary, non-persistent storage possible on IPFS?

Tags: ipfs

I'm looking to store data temporarily on IPFS, probably using a JS library, may or may not host an IPFS node.  The technology is so new it isn't easy to locate answers. Please, I appreciate your help, especially in both cases of hosted and non-hosted solutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is only stored persistently on nodes that have "pinned" the content hash. Nodes that request data will cache it for an indeterminate amount of time (as the data is immutable and referenced by hash, the cache would always be valid).

Once you are finished with the data you could remove it from your node, and as long as no one else requested it it would gradually disappear from the network. You could not rely on that happening (for instance if you have a requirement that the data be inaccessible after a certain amount of time).

You would need to be running your own node to initially host the file